# How to copy and paste python pandas pivot table result to an existing workbook in a specific cell range?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to copy the results of a pivot table created in python using pandas and paste it in an existing workbook in a specific without erasing whatever it is in the surrounding cells. Can this be done? I'm new with python.

I'm able to save the pivot table to a new workbook, but we don't want to manually copy the pivot results to the existing workbook. I found this web-page: 
https://yagisanatode.com/2017/11/18/copy-and-paste-ranges-in-excel-with-openpyxl-and-python-3/  that uses OpenPyXl load the existing workbook as a template and can paste the data to an specific range, but sincerely, I did not understand it

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...)
sql_command = """...."""
data = pd.read_sql(sql_command, cnxn)
table1 = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['LTV_Bucket'], 
                        columns= ['Vintage'],
                        values=['AmrtCost'], aggfunc=[lambda x: sum(x)], fill_value=0)
```

I'm expecting to paste the pivot table results into the existing workbook in the range B10:G12 without erasing whatever it is in the surrounding cells. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: when you say copy, do you actually mean copy or do you mean save to a specific place in an existing workbook? If you're just trying to copy you can call `to_clipboard` and then select where you want to paste it and paste it. [to_clipboard](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html)

Comment: Save it to a specific place in an existing workbook. For example, the result should be place in the range B10:G12 in in the worksheet 'Data'. It cannot be place in the Column A or in the first 9 lines because I have other information in those cells.